# Updating Blazor WebAssembly to .NET 7 breaks index.html script loading

Tags: javascript, .net, blazor, webassembly

Within the index.html file, after

> ```
> <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
> ```

I previously added

> ```
> <script>
>     Blazor.start().then(function () {
>         // JSHelper.js
>         var JSHelperScript = document.createElement('script');
>         JSHelperScript.setAttribute('src', '/_content/SampleApp/scripts/MyJS.js');
>         document.head.appendChild(JSHelperScript);
>     });
> </script>
> ```

Which worked as intended when using .NET 6, but now that I've updated to VSP2022 17.4.0 and updated the projects to .NET 7, it seems this code is no longer working because the functions in MyJS.js are not available.  My preference is to inject it like this because I (want to) believe it cachebusts (maybe not), as opposed to something like adding

> ```
> <script src="/_content/SampleApp/scripts/MyJS.js"></script>
> ```

..which does work, but presumably caches, which I'm trying to avoid.  Whether it cachebusts or not, I'm more interested in restoring this injection code, if only to understand why it broke.